# Why my airflow does not run as schedule_interval?

Tags: python, airflow

```
dag = DAG(
dag_id='error_config',
default_args=default_args,
schedule_interval= '*/10 * * * *')
```

my dag's args are like this, but this dag only run normally when I clicked the "run" button on the web page, but cannot run automatic after next schedule_interval

Comment: what is your default_args looks like? especially your 'start_date'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest check which version of airflow you are running, there has been an upgrade on version 1.8+ for the usage of **start_date**. The detail can be found here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/UPDATING.md#less-forgiving-scheduler-on-dynamic-start_date

So datetime.now() is not considered a best practice, and could cause DAGs not being scheduled. You may want to set a fixed date as your start date as well as a new dag name.